# Is the name of German company Siemens related to the unit of conductance?

Tags: physics, units

We have heard about the name of the famous German company Siemens.My friend said that this is because they were the first to introduce conductance bridges and hence named after the unit of conductance Siemens.
But in the Wikipedia article I saw that Siemens was founded by Werner von Siemens and thus the name.
So,is my friend wrong?What is the real reason behind the name?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Maybe [Ernst Werner von Siemens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_von_Siemens) can be useful ...

Comment: Sounds like you already have your answer. Do you have any reason to believe your friend over Wikipedia or, you know, [the official company website](http://www.siemens.com/about/en/history.htm)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [unit "Siemens"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_(unit)) was only introduced in 1971 whereas the [company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens) was founded the mid-19th century.

Both get their name from the same person, [Werner von Siemens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_von_Siemens).

Comment: So,the conductance bridge theory that my friend said is not true?

Comment: Ehm, yes. To spell it out for you: there is no way that a company was named after something that did not exist for another 100 years. (Assuming the absence of time travel.) That said, assuming that Siemens' company was indeed the first conductance bridges (I did not check that fact), this may be (part of) why the SI unit got to be named after him.